# VHDL 2 bit adder circuit

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, vhdl

im trying to build a counter to be used to access RAM addresses
I used a 2bit adder made from full adders
Upon reset of registers, the outputs are '0000', this value is fed into the adder circuit along with an increment of '0001'
It calculates the next address which is fed into a register, register outputs the calculated address back into the adder for the next calculation
I tested the functionality of the adder and registers, they are fully working but combining them together proves some difficulty, here is my simulation using GHDL + GTKWAVE

[image]

```
--Calculates next address
--Moore machine implementation -> 1 Combinational circuit and Memory
--Register implements Memory outputs intial address, inputs next address
--n bit adder implements address calculation combinational circuit

--Declare external 4 bit register entity and architecture
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity reg_4 is
    port(
        clk: in std_logic;
        d1,d2,d3,d4: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        o1, o2, o3, o4: out std_logic
    );

end reg_4;

architecture behavioural of reg_4 is
begin
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if(reset = '1') then
            o1 <= '0';
            o2 <= '0';
            o3 <= '0';
            o4 <= '0';
        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
            o1 <= d1;
            o2 <= d2;
            o3 <= d3;
            o4 <= d4;
       end if;
    end process;
end behavioural;


-- General 1-bit adder circuit, configurable for instantiation
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity adder1 is
    port(
            cin : in  std_logic;
            a,b : in std_logic;
            cout: out std_logic;
            dout: out std_logic 
        );
end adder1;

architecture behavioural of adder1 is
begin
    
    cout <= (cin AND (a OR b)) OR (a AND b);
    dout <= (a XOR b XOR cin);

end behavioural;

-- Declare main Address Calculator entity and architecture
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

--Declare main addressCalc entity port signals
entity addressCalc is
    port(
        reset: in std_logic;
        clk: in std_logic;
        increment: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        nextAddress: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
    );
end addressCalc;

--Declare and define the addressCalc architecture
architecture BEHAVIOURAL of addressCalc is
    
    component adder1 port(
                            cin : in  std_logic;
                            a,b : in std_logic;
                            cout: out std_logic;
                            dout: out std_logic 
                        );
    end component;
    
    component reg_4 port(
                            clk: in std_logic;
                            d1,d2,d3,d4: in std_logic;
                            reset: in std_logic;
                            o1, o2, o3, o4: out std_logic
                        );
    end component;  
    
    --Adder to adder signals
    constant initialCin: std_logic := '0';
    signal adder1_2: std_logic;
    signal adder2_3: std_logic;
    signal adder3_4: std_logic;
    
    --Adder to register signals
    signal adder_ff: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    signal ff_adder: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    
    --Adder to addressCalc signals
    signal ac_adder: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

    --reg_4 port <-> addressCalc port signals
    signal d1,d2,d3,d4: std_logic;
    signal o1,o2,o3,o4: std_logic;
    

begin

    reg_4_i: reg_4 port map(
                            clk=>clk,d1=>d1,d2=>d2,d3=>d3,d4=>d4,reset=>reset,o1=>o1,o2=>o2,o3=>o3,o4=>o4
                            );
                            
    adder1_1_i: adder1 port map(
                            cin=>initialCin, a=>ac_adder(0), b=>ff_adder(0), dout=>adder_ff(0), cout=>adder1_2
                            );
                            
    adder1_2_i: adder1 port map(
                            cin=>adder1_2, a=>ac_adder(1), b=>ff_adder(1), dout=>adder_ff(1), cout=>adder_ff(2)
                            );
                            
    -- adder1_3_i: adder1 port map(
                            -- cin=>cout2_3, a=>increment(2), b=>o3, dout=>dout_dn(2), cout=>cout2_3
                            -- );
                            
    -- adder1_4_i: adder1 port map(
                            -- cin=>cout3_4, a=>increment(3), b=>o4, dout=>dout_dn(3), cout=>nextAddress(4)
                            -- );
                        
    --Connect Adder outputs to addressCalc output ports     
    
    -- nextAddress(2) <= dout_dn(2);
    -- nextAddress(3) <= dout_dn(3);
    

    -- d3 <= dout_dn(2);
    -- d4 <= dout_dn(3);
    
    --Assign Adder output ports to AddressCalc ports
    

    process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            
            ff_adder(0) <= o1;
            ff_adder(1) <= o2;
            ac_adder(0) <=increment(0);
            ac_adder(1) <=increment(1);
            
            d1 <= adder_ff(0);
            d2 <= adder_ff(1);
            d3 <= adder_ff(2);
            
            nextAddress(0) <= o1;
            nextAddress(1) <= o2;
            nextAddress(2) <= o3;
            
            
        end if;
    end process;
    

    

end BEHAVIOURAL;

TEST BENCH
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;


entity addr_calc_tb is
end addr_calc_tb;

architecture behavioural of addr_calc_tb is
    
    signal clk: std_logic;
    signal reset: std_logic;
    signal increment: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal nextAddress: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    constant clock_period: time:= 1 ns;
    signal stop_clock: boolean;
    
    component addressCalc port(
                                reset: in std_logic;
                                clk: in std_logic;
                                increment : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
                                nextAddress: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
                            );
    end component;
begin

    addressCalc_i: addressCalc port map(
                                            reset=>reset,
                                            clk=>clk,
                                            increment=>increment,
                                            nextAddress=>nextAddress
                                        );

    clocking: process begin
        while not stop_clock 
            loop
                clk <= '0', '1' after clock_period/2;
                wait for clock_period;
            end loop;
            wait;
    end process;
    
    
    stimulus: process begin
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 1 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        increment <= "01";
        assert false report "Ending test";
        wait;
    end process;
    
end behavioural;
```

Comment: what difficulty? where is your testbench?

Comment: if it is only a two bit added, why not do a lookup table, there is a really low number of results

Comment: I will be using more bits but i just lowered the number of bits for testing
It will be too tedious to build the circuit for larger number of bits for addresses

Comment: This is VHDL, not schematic capture. Just do +1 to a numeric type and let the synthesis handle the implementation. It will rollover properly, etc.

Comment: I dont understand i am using GHDL compiler and GTKWave simulator not any IDE like Vivado or XIlinx ISE

Comment: Ideally i would like to get rid of the Uninitialised values seen in the simulation and allow counting to up to 111 instead of 100

Comment: You've already got `IEEE.Numeric_Std.all`in there -- make use of it! If you don't understand what it's for, there's plenty of reference material on the Interwebs.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the power of an HDL at your disposal. There's no reason that your `addressCalc` needs to be any more complicated than this:

```
architecture BEHAVIOURAL of addressCalc is
  signal address_reg: unsigned (2 downto 0);
begin
  process (clk) begin
    if rising_edge (clk) then
      if (reset = '1') then
        address_reg <= to_unsigned (0, address_reg'length);
      else
        address_reg <= address_reg + unsigned (increment);
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  nextAddress <= std_logic_vector (address_reg);
end BEHAVIOURAL;
```

This compiles perfectly well with GHDL and the libraries you've already specified.

I'm not sure that this code behaves **exactly** as you intended — you've got a lot of extra registers in your implementation, and I didn't try to duplicate all of that. I just wanted to give you the gist of what's possible.

Comment: Im not sure whether you know that any if statement in a clk condition is considered extremely bad design or not

Comment: Because during a rising_edge, the calculation of an output should not change depending on other signals

Comment: @Luminous If you have a clocked design, why not express logical conditions with an `if`? Do you have any decent reference?

Comment: I don't know where you heard that *"any if statement in a clk condition is considered extremely bad design"*, because it isn't -- in fact, it's an extremely common HDL idiom. You can think of an `if` statement as a mux. Putting it inside a `rising_edge(...)` simply means that there is an edge-triggered register at the output of the mux.